# sum of power of prime factor given find number

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Here Therowm given -
$f(x)=$sum of power of prime factor of $x$.
Now if $f(x)$ is given then find the least value of $x$;

Eg: $f(x)=2$

so if

1. check for $x=2$ then $f(x)=1$
2. check for $x=3$ then $f(x)=1$
3. check for $x=4$ then $f(x)=2$ (i.e., $x=2^2$,and we know that $f(x)$ is some of power of prime factor so $f(x)$ here is $2$)

so the Answer is $x=4$.

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is here, but if it's what I think it is, `2^f[x]`? Did you mean to post this is some other SE site? This one is for the *software* *Mathematica*...

Comment: Do I get you right that $f(\prod p_k^{e_k})=\sum e_k$?

Answer (score 1):

The smallest $x$ with $f(x)=y$ will be $2^y$. This is clear as $f(pn)=f(2n)$ for any prime $p$.